# Is IT possible to make a ext4 external HD completely open?

Tags: permissions, ext4

I bought a new external HD in order to use it like a usb key to exchange files between different computers, and I formatted it using ext4

The problem is that everytime I upload some files I have to change the permission, in order to edit something with another computer or user, and this way creates me too many problems so i would like to know if there is a way to avoid this and makin the HD totally open by default?  (sort of how FAT allows it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no filesystem that both uses *nix semantics *and* allows you to arbitrarily violate them.

Comment: well I´ll have to use FAT hoping I´ll have no problem file corruption... thanks

Comment: Necroposing, but consider `UDF` filesystem for such use cases. It is usually the most compatible and does support files larger than 4 gigabytes.